# Will essential oil diffuser trigger the smoke detector?

Tags: smoke-detectors

I saw many posts online saying that the essential oil diffuser will not set up the smoke detector. However, there were actually some posts online saying that its diffuser sets off the smoke detector. Which one should I believe?

Thanks

Comment: believe both ... all smoke detectors are not the same ... also, all diffusers are not the same

Answer (score 1):

They can set off alarms, it depends on the density of the mist and ability to reach the smoke detector. The [installation instructions that come with a smoke detector](https://www.kidde.com/home-safety/en/us/media/Bed_Hall_Living_10_Year_Smokes_low_tcm126-27832.pdf), say to avoid bath and shower rooms and other humid areas.

There are essentially two types of detectors, photoelectric and ionization detectors.

Photoelectric have a light transmitter and receiver, if enough light is obstructed it alarms.

Ionization have a transmitter and receiver that when enough conductible particles come between between them static electricity will conduct and alarm.